# oracle rman connecting to a database in not mount state

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g, scripting, rman

When connected to oracle database through rman directly from the terminal, everything works fine, but when the same connection string is executed through a shell script rman connects to the database in a no mount state, not sure why, using oralce 11g, oracle Linux, and the connection  string is :

```
rman target / catalog (userName)/(password)@//(IPADDRESS):(PORT)/SYNDEV
```

Answer (score 2):

[Kris Johnston](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68832/kris-johnston) said in a comment:

> nomount/mount/open are the states of the database... something can't connect to the db one way and connect as nomount, and connect to the same db a different way and connect as mount or open.  It doesn't work like that.  It sounds like you are connecting to *a different* database altogether.  To check, verify the dbid's are the same/different when you connect via RMAN.  Also, instead of connecting to rman, connect to sqlplus using your various connection methods, then check: select status from v$instance; select dbid from v$database; (have to bring the db into mount state to query v$database).

Issue has been fixed. Kris, your explanation actually made sense, I am not sure why, but there were multiple Oracle instances running in top for the same database, so I had to kill all those and use the same SID strings in the scripts, with the exact case, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

To connect to RMAN from the operating system command line and hide authentication information, you must first start RMAN and then perform either of the following actions:

1. Run the CONNECT commands at the RMAN prompt. ...
2. Run a command file at the RMAN prompt that contains the connection
   information.